# Freemarker - only use getter for beans

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

I have some builder functions in my entities, which cannot be handled by freemarker.

For example, I have the following bean/entity:

```
public class User{

    private Long number;

    public Long getNumber(){
        return this.number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Long number){
        this.number = number;
    }

    public User number(Long number){
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

And my freemarker template is something like this:

```
<span>${user.number}</span>
```

which I process on the fly as follows:

```
User user = getUser();
Map<String, Object> context = new HashMap<>();
contaxt.put("user", user);
Configuration configuration = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_0);
configuration.setObjectWrapper(new BeansWrapper(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_0));
Template t = new Template("usertpl", template, configuration);
String result = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(t, model);
```

Since my entity contains a method "number(Long)", freemarker tries to use this, which is actually a setter - so it is not working.

I know, that i can use the getter in the template, but the template should be defined by users (where I think `${user.number}` is more comprehensible than `${user.getNumber()}` for those who are not programmers)

So, I'm searching for another solution...

Is there a possibility to configure freemarker so that it only uses the getter (`getNumber()`) to access the property, instead of using the `number(Long)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure `BeansWrapper` like that with `setMethodAppearanceFineTuner`. For the sake of hasty copy-pasters, I will use here a builder instead of `new`, `DefaultObjectWrapper` instead of `BeansWrapper`, and `VERSION_2_3_25` instead of `VERSION_2_3_0`, but this also works with your setup:

```
DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder owb = new DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_25);
owb.setMethodAppearanceFineTuner(new MethodAppearanceFineTuner() {
    @Override
    public void process(MethodAppearanceDecisionInput in, MethodAppearanceDecision out) {
        out.setMethodShadowsProperty(false);
    }
});
cfg.setObjectWrapper(owb.build());
```

As of the "experimental" disclaimers in the JavaDoc, don't worry, these will leave experimental status in 2.3.26.

Comment: I finally hat some time to check it and it's working now. Thanks!