# Freemarker prevent Template from using setter Method

Tags: java, freemarker

I am starting using Freemarker to generate emails.
The problem is, that Freemarker allows invoking java methods, which is fine, but on the otherside, I don't want to allow the user changing the data.

```
((showSubjects)) Titel: ${ MainSubject.ProductTitle} ${MainSubject.setTitle("Hallo World!")}
```

This code changes the title!

Have you any idea to avoid that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Freemarker - only use getter for beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39747696/freemarker-only-use-getter-for-beans)

Comment: @vinS thank you for your comment.
I don't think, that this question solves my problem. 
hier is the discription of the method setMethodShadowsProperty:
`so if you have
     *     both a property and a method called "foo", then in the template
     *     <tt>myObject.foo</tt> will return the method itself instead
     *     of the property value, which is often undesirable.`

Comment: If you find an answer to your question (well done!) it is more appropriate to make your own answer. It is easier to read and see other answers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [rjy7 - Cornell University](https://github.com/UniMelb-source/vitro-core/blob/master/webapp/src/edu/cornell/mannlib/vitro/webapp/web/beanswrappers/ReadOnlyBeansWrapper.java), the solution could be done through setting a ReadOnlyBeansWrapper by preventing the using of setters (a method which starts with "set", or which returns void).

```
@Override
protected void finetuneMethodAppearance(Class cls, Method method, MethodAppearanceDecision decision) {

// How to define a setter? This is a weak approximation: a method whose name
// starts with "set" or returns void.
if ( method.getName().startsWith("set") ) {
    decision.setExposeMethodAs(null);

} else if ( method.getReturnType().getName().equals("void") ) {
    decision.setExposeMethodAs(null);

} else {

    Class<?> declaringClass = method.getDeclaringClass();
    if (declaringClass.equals(java.lang.Object.class)) {
        decision.setExposeMethodAs(null);

    } else {
        Package pkg = declaringClass.getPackage();
        if (pkg.getName().equals("java.util")) {
            decision.setExposeMethodAs(null);
        }
    }
}
```

I used it, und it works fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide all methods, you should set the `exposureLevel` of the `ObjectWrapper` to `EXPOSE_PROPERTIES_ONLY` (see [BeansWrapper.setExposureLevel](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/api/freemarker/ext/beans/BeansWrapper.html#setExposureLevel-int-)). Then you can still write `foo.bar`, which will internally call `foo.getBar()`. As assignment to JavaBean properties is not supported by FreeMarker, and the setter method itself is not exposed because it's a method, the template won't be able to change the exposed properties.